# Only show first 25 data items in bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a large data set with 1000 items, and I would like to only show the first 25 items into my bar chart. I have the bar chart working but it shows all 1000 items.

Here is my d3 code:

```
d3.json(myData, function (data) {

    var width = 1150;
    var height 5000;

    //Create the canvas
    var canvas = d3.select("#barChart") 
        .append("svg")                  
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);        


    //Create the rectangles for the bar chart
    canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data.results)             
        .enter()                   
        .append("rect")                 
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 15)            
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return i * 25;
        })
    

});
```

I've messed with the `data(data.results)` section trying to do things like:

```
.data(data.results, function(d,i) {
    return i < 25;
})
```

But can't quite get it to work. What can I try next?

P.S the data looks like this: this is just the top 4 of 1000.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "last_updated": "2017-08-19"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "term": "term1",
      "count": 1569
    },
    {
      "term": "term2",
      "count": 1375
    },
    {
      "term": "term3",
      "count": 1372
    },
    {
      "term": "term4",
      "count": 1208
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is an array, try `data.slice(0, 25)` with "data" being your array of course.

EDIT: with your data structure, you can do `results.slice(0, 25)` and use that.

Comment: awesome this worked! ill accept your answer when it lets me. thanks

Comment: can you explain the parameters of the slice method though? why is it in the format (x, y)

Comment: The `slice()` method returns a new array based on a starting and ending index position of the array you give it. If you did `results.slice()` - it would return a copy of the entire array for you. Here's more to explain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice